# Respond to previous comments Gerrit

Tags: gerrit

Question about Gerrit; the open source code review web application. Version 2.12.7.
Problem I have is that whenever I push a new commit, someone reviews and before even responding to their comments I upload a new patch set because I made a mistake or something. Now, I when I click on the file, their comments are gone. And I can't reply anymore...

I am also using the PhpStorm extension, is it possible to comment on previous comments on either?

Maybe I am overlooking something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you push the commit to Gerrit, it creates the first patchset of the change. The reviewers comments are made in this patchset.

When you push the second commit and Gerrit creates the second patchset of the same change, the "focus" in the change page (in the web UI) is changed to the second patchset, so you don't see the first patchset comments.

But the good news is: you can change that! You only need to select the first patchset and the comments will be showed again. The 2.12.7 is a very old version so I don't know exacty where do you need to click to change from patchset 2 to patchset 1, but I'm sure you'll find some clickable button like "Patch Sets (2/2)" in the change screen.